# Joining multiple tables in laravel query builder results in duplication

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use Laravel Query Builder to join 2 tables.

Here's my query for joining 2 tables

```
  $instructors = DB::table('instructors')
                ->join('instructor_courses', 'instructors.id', '=','instructor_courses.instructor_id')
                ->where('instructor_courses.course_id', $schedule->course_id)
                ->where('instructor_courses.position', 'Instructor')
                ->whereNull('instructor_courses.deleted_at')
                ->whereNull('instructors.deleted_at')
                ->get();
```

The code let me join the table properly however this results to multiple duplication. Take a look at the result passed in select tag

[image]

Here's the schema I have

**Instructor Table**
[image]

**Instructor Courses Table**
[image]

Basically what I want to achieve is to display a record without duplication. Is there a better approach in joining multiple table like this one? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use `groupBy` for `instructors.id`

```
 $instructors = DB::table('instructors')
            ->join('instructor_courses', 'instructors.id', '=','instructor_courses.instructor_id')
            ->where('instructor_courses.course_id', $schedule->course_id)
            ->where('instructor_courses.position', 'Instructor')
            ->whereNull('instructor_courses.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('instructors.deleted_at')
            ->groupBy('instructors.id') //add a line
            ->get();
```

Comment: I will try the group by method

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the `->distinct()` function in laravel to prevent duplicates in selecting data.

```
$instructors = DB::table('instructors')
            ->join('instructor_courses', 'instructors.id', '=','instructor_courses.instructor_id')
            ->where('instructor_courses.course_id', $schedule->course_id)
            ->where('instructor_courses.position', 'Instructor')
            ->whereNull('instructor_courses.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('instructors.deleted_at')
            ->groupBy('instructors.id')
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
```

Comment: This is wrong, they are not duplicates, it's just a one to many relation which means he just has to groupBy as the above answer